# Password strength plugin that works with jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How would I go about making this [password strength plugin](https://github.com/ablanco/jquery.pwstrength.bootstrap) work with jquery validate.

1. If the password strength has a score of 50 or less,
2. The field is classed as invalid and will not submit the form
3. Shows validation message explaining why.
4. Once password reaches required strength, form validates as normal (same as how validate works by default)

The password has 2 methods to extend easily and update the validate plugin when the field is valid:

1. onLoad
2. onKeyUp

So my question/part most confused about: how would this work with jquery validate creating a new validation requirement?

Comment: Set up a jsFiddle so we have a starting point.

Comment: You can try also [pStrength - Password Strength Checker](http://www.accountspassword.com/password-strength-jquery-plugin) a jQuery plugin which can be easely integrated in any website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-password-validation/

This plugin is specifically for the jQuery Validation plugin (authored by the same guy, JÖRN ZAEFFERER)

Comment: The plugin download is no longer there.

Comment: @DylanGlockler - When I answered two years ago, it was there.

Comment: You can still find it at [`github`](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation.password)